# Redirect users based on browser language (not in php)

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

My website will be in 3 languages. French (fr) is the default language.
The structure of the site is the following:

Root directory (note: I'm not using php files, just plain html)

```
/fr/
    Index.html
    About-us.html
    Contact.html

/en/
    Index.html
    About-us.html
    Contact.html

/de/
    Index.html
    About-us.html
    Contact.html
```

I got  questions:

- What is the best practice to redirect users based on their web browser language? Via htaccess?
- Do I need a index.html page at root level (for SEO reason or any other reason) ? The French index.html perhaps?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html - One you will in there is `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^.*(de|es|fr|it|ja|ru|en).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=prefer-language:%1]` and this could also be useful http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57524/htaccess-language-detection-redirect-and-friendly-urls - You could probably use JS too, but that's not the most efficient method, if JS is disabled on the client side.

Comment: Sidenote: You know that you can use the `.shtml` file extension to do includes (server setups work like that by default) and I for one have been using this method for years. However, you can instruct your server to treat `.html` files as `.shtml` in order to make your site more manageable when it comes to using the same headers/nav/footers, rather than having to update a whole bunch of files one by one.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of that, this is good to know!

Comment: Youre welcome Greg. Plus, SSI with `.shtml` allows you (least mine do) to include pretty much any file types including `.php`, however would be limited to a certain extent if you want to run certain PHP directives.

Comment: You're asking for an objective "best practice", of which there isn't any such beast. Search for _how to redirect based upon browser locale_ and examine the various techniques you find. Each technique will have strengths and weaknesses, and it is up to you to figure out which is best. If you have a mentor, ask them as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Super easy tool here:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/redirection-by-language/

Makes life incredibly easy for htaccess redirects based on the browser's language.

Example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (fr) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /fr/index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /en/index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (de) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /de/index.html [L]
```

This is a hard redirect, the browser's location bar will indeed show the new page. Though, this is better for UX than an internal redirect masking the URL.

To answer your question, it is highly regarded that an index.html provides the best UX. However, that's essentially because people have come to expect this in general (website.com/en/, website.com/fr/, etc.). SEO-wise, no, you wouldn't get dinged if you didn't follow that same structure.

Best practice is to use your best guess (like the htaccess), and still offer a menu for switching languages. Plus, you'll also need a fallback for if the Accept-Language isn't actually defined (like going to /en/ by default). This could be a final line in the htaccess, or it could simply be an `index.html` at the root level, where `.htaccess` is.

Other than that, there's not a tremendous amount that goes into localization.

Comment: Thanks! Should I put an index.html file in the root directory as well in your opinion? (for instance if the language browser is none of these 3 languages?) Or is there a rewrite rule to redirect everything, that is not EN or DE, to the French page by default?

Comment: I would certainly put a default index.html as well, that was simply in your most common language, which also provided a menu to choose their language. Sorry, forgot to include that.

Comment: I used `RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/ [R,L]` to have a more precise redirect and prevent a redirect loop.