# Symfony redirect user to url country

Tags: php, symfony

I'm looking for a PHP / Symfony code to redirect the user to another link according to his place of connection www.mondomain.fr/fr and www.mondomaine.fr/pt etc ... How can I do this ? I have included in my roads this already:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}", name="homepage")
 *
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $boutton = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Boutton')->findAll();
    $image = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Images')->findAll();

    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        'boutton' => $boutton,
        'images' => $image
    ));
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions (not a PHP one) is to redirect based on browser language, you can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36985914).

You can also detect IP and redirect based on that, you can use [this](https://github.com/aferrandini/Maxmind-GeoIp) library to get the country/locale of the IP address and then redirect based on that.